Difference between length in a Data Frame vs a Matrix
When calculating the length of a matrix, it brings the result as the product of the number of rows and columns, but when calculating the length of a data frame, it brings the results as the number of columns. Why does not calculate it the same way as a matrix?
Example:
a <- matrix(1:10, nrow = 2, ncol = 5)
nrow(a)
ncol(a)

length(a)

The outputs are 2,5 and 10.
b <- data.frame(1:2, matrix(1:10, nrow = 2, ncol = 5))

nrow(b)
ncol(b)
length(b)

The outputs are 2,6,6

This is due to the internal representation of a matrix which is a vector with attributes vs a data.frame which is list of columns with attributes. length is the length of that vector or list.  Look at dput(a) and dput(b) to see the internal representations.
